# Why is my SwiftUI view not updating when the model changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I update the content of an existing row in a List?

The print statement shows that the button is updating the Bool, but the View does not update .

the content (button) moves as expected, but the action and formating does not change as expected.

the code for the page I am using:

```
struct NotificationView: View {
@ObservedObject  var notificationVModel: NotificationVModel = NotificationVModel()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List(notificationVModel.notificationarray,id:\.NotificationName){notificationVV in
            ZStack {
                if notificationVV.isShgowen {
                    Color (.green).opacity(0.1)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                }
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        notificationVV.changTogle()
                        print("\(notificationVV.isShgowen)")
                        
                        
                    }, label: {
                        ZStack{
                            Circle()
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0 / 255, green: 175 / 255, blue: 80 / 255))
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            Image(systemName: "bell")
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }                            })
                    VStack{
                        HStack {
                            if notificationVV.isShgowen{
                                Text("true")
                                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 10))
                            }
                            Text(notificationVV.NotificationName)
                                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 20))
                            Spacer()
                            Text(notificationVV.NotifivationDate)
                                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Medium", size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }.padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
                        Text(notificationVV.NotificationDiscrip)
                            .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 11))
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
                    }
                }.padding()
            }
        }
       .navigationTitle("Notification")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

}

The ViewModel

```
class NotificationVModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var notificationarray : [NotificationV] = [
    NotificationV(NotificationName: "Notification 1", NotificationDiscrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consec tetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum doloramet,consec tetur adipiscing elit sit ipi piscing… ", NotifivationDate: "04/02/2021", isShgowen: false),        NotificationV(NotificationName: "Notification 2", NotificationDiscrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consec tetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum doloramet,consec tetur adipiscing elit sit ipi piscing… ", NotifivationDate: "05/03/2021", isShgowen: true),
]
```

}

The model

```
class NotificationV : ObservableObject{
let objectWillChange = ObservableObjectPublisher()
@Published var NotificationName : String = ""
@Published var NotificationDiscrip: String = ""
@Published var NotifivationDate:String = ""
@Published var isShgowen:Bool = false

init(NotificationName: String, NotificationDiscrip: String, NotifivationDate: String, isShgowen: Bool) {
        self.NotificationName = NotificationName
        self.NotificationDiscrip = NotificationDiscrip
        self.NotifivationDate = NotifivationDate
        self.isShgowen = isShgowen
    }

func changTogle(){
    if isShgowen == false {
        isShgowen = true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are publishing an array so my guess is that the view is reacting to changes to the array but not to changes to elements in the array.

Comment: is NotificationV a class or struct?

Comment: NotificationV is class

Comment: Your model (NotificationV) should be struct.

Comment: when i chenge it to struct the compiler give me an error (Cannot assign to property: 'notificationVV' is a 'let' constant)

Comment: My mistake. Assumed it is not a ObservableObject.

Comment: Why are you using NotificationVModel?

Comment: that's what i know im news in swiftui, if u have any other solution tell me

Comment: @AmineElhajjaji check the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use **struct** rather than  **class** for the **NotificationV**.
- Create a new view for the buttons and send both your **viewmodel** and **model** to the new **view**.
- Find **index of model**

Fore more info, read this tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

---

```
struct NotificationView: View {
    @ObservedObject  var notificationVModel: NotificationVModel = NotificationVModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(notificationVModel.notificationarray,id:\.NotificationName){notificationVV in
                ZStack {
                    if notificationVV.isShowen {
                        Color (.green).opacity(0.1)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                        
                    }
                    HStack{
                        ToggleNotification(notifications: $notificationVModel.notificationarray, notificationV: notificationVV)
                        VStack{
                            HStack {
                                Text(notificationVV.isShowen ? "true": "false")
                                if notificationVV.isShowen {
                                    Text("true")
                                        .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 10))
                                }
                                Text(notificationVV.NotificationName)
                                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 20))
                                Spacer()
                                Text(notificationVV.NotifivationDate)
                                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Medium", size: 12))
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }.padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
                            Text(notificationVV.NotificationDiscrip)
                                .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 11))
                                .lineLimit(nil)
                                .padding(.leading).padding(.trailing)
                        }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Notification")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}


struct ToggleNotification:View {
    
    @Binding var notifications: [NotificationV]
    var notificationV: NotificationV
    
    var index:Int? {
        notifications.firstIndex { $0.NotificationName == notificationV.NotificationName}
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            notifications[index!].isShowen.toggle()
            print("\($notifications[index!].isShowen)")
 
        }, label: {
            ZStack{
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0 / 255, green: 175 / 255, blue: 80 / 255))
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                Image(systemName: "bell")
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
        })
    }
}


struct NotificationV {
    var NotificationName : String = ""
    var NotificationDiscrip: String = ""
    var NotifivationDate:String = ""
    var isShowen:Bool = false
    
    init(NotificationName: String, NotificationDiscrip: String, NotifivationDate: String, isShowen: Bool) {
        self.NotificationName = NotificationName
        self.NotificationDiscrip = NotificationDiscrip
        self.NotifivationDate = NotifivationDate
        self.isShowen = isShowen
    }
}


class NotificationVModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var notificationarray : [NotificationV] = [
        NotificationV(NotificationName: "Notification 1", NotificationDiscrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consec tetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum doloramet,consec tetur adipiscing elit sit ipi piscing… ", NotifivationDate: "04/02/2021", isShowen: false),        NotificationV(NotificationName: "Notification 2", NotificationDiscrip: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consec tetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum doloramet,consec tetur adipiscing elit sit ipi piscing… ", NotifivationDate: "05/03/2021", isShowen: true),
    ]
    
}
```

---

*Follow case conventions. Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.*

https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

---

## Update

As of now, **NotificationV** must unique **NotificationName**. Regardless of that, **NotificationV** should confirms to both **Identifiable**, **Equatable** protocols and use the following in **ToggleNotification**

```
var index:Int? {
    notifications.firstIndex { $0 == notificationV}
}
```

#### NotificationV

```
struct NotificationV: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var NotificationName : String = ""
    var NotificationDiscrip: String = ""
    var NotifivationDate:String = ""
    var isShowen:Bool = false
    
    init(NotificationName: String, NotificationDiscrip: String, NotifivationDate: String, isShowen: Bool) {
        self.NotificationName = NotificationName
        self.NotificationDiscrip = NotificationDiscrip
        self.NotifivationDate = NotifivationDate
        self.isShowen = isShowen
    }
}
```

Doing so you always find correct **NotificationV** even if they do not have unique name.